# Showing alerts when Meteor user is updated

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working on a Meteor application. Occasionally, the server updates the current user with data from an external database. When that happens, I would like to display an alert on whatever page of the application is open on client side. I know the Meteor.user gets updated automatically on the client, but I am clueless as to how and where to get the application to monitor the user for changes and react to them. Any ideas on this?

The user update is triggered via a post to the server:

```
Router.map(function() {
this.route('/reload_user', {where: 'server'}).post(function() {
    var data = this.request.body;
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ "profile.id": data.id });

    var data = Account.getAccountInfo(apiKey, secretKey);           
    Meteor.users.update(user._id, {
        $set: {
            "profile.paywall": data.paywall,
        }
    });
    this.response.end();
});
```

Comment: If you share your code we might be able to help you out.

Comment: Hmm, it is a gigantic application that I am not the original author of, and I am pretty new to working with Meteor. Are there any particular parts that could be useful?

Comment: I believe the snippet of code that gets called upon the user is updated should work as a starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, you want to expose a publication for the user collection. On the client, you want to auto subscribe to that publication and handle the changed event:

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function() {
  Meteor.users.find().observe({
    changed: function(item) {
      alert(item);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you are specifically wanting to check the current user, you can pass a find filter like so: <code>Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()})</code>

Comment: Note that 'autosubscribe' is deprecated. Today you would use 'Tracker.autorun()` to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this:

In the success callback of your post request, set a session variable like so: `Session.set("userUpdated", true)`

Then I'd create a global template helper to return the value of this session variable. Because of how Meteor works with reactive variables such as Session.get, it will automatically update when you set it.

```
Template.registerHelper("userUpdatedHelper", function () {
  return Session.get("userUpdated");
}
```

Then in any of your templates, you can simply use something like this:

```
{{#if userUpdatedHelper}} //true when you set it to true, otherwise undefined
  //show alert messaging here
{{/if}}
```

Something like that is where I'd start.